# Is there a way to do ECS Blue Green deployment using aws codedeploy with a shared ALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-code-deploy, blue-green-deployment

I have a shared ALB which is used by multiple fargate service(s) by configuring host header rule to forward the traffic to specific target group(s)

Is it possible to do blue green deployment using codedeploy for ECS fargate application by only using one shared ALB?

I try to do POC, but I cannot find a place to configure the host header condition on code deploy

Answer (score 0):

You can perform Blue-green deployment using a shared ALB across multiple `CodeDeploy` applications/deployment groups. In the deployment group containing `ALB`, `TargetGroupOne`, `TargetGroupTwo`, the deployment performs a string comparison for the target group names defined for the deployment group within the load balancer specified and co-ordinate the traffic shifting as per the chosen strategy. The target group can be defined in the default rule or other rule to include path, host, header based routing or a combination of that. CodeDeploy would find active rule serving 100% of the target group traffic and then switch to the other target group defined in the same deployment group.